# In vite, is there a way to update the root html name from index.html

Tags: vite

I'm trying to update an existing project to vite but i read in the docs Vite expects an index.html file to work from.
Is there anyway to specify another file name from which vite should build?
in my case main.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The entry point is configured in [`build.rollupOptions.input`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#input):

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
export default defineConfig({
  ⋮
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        app: './index.html', // default
      },
    },
  },
})
```

You can change that to `main.html`, as shown below. When serving the app, you'll have to manually navigate to `/main.html`, but you could configure [`server.open`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-open) to open that file automatically:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  ⋮
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        app: './main.html',
      },
    },
  },
  server: {
    open: '/main.html',
  },
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-change-entry-point?file=vite.config.js)

Answer (score 17):

If you're trying to change not just the name of the root HTML page but also the *path* to it, changing `build` or `server` options won't help.  For example, if you want to load `<project root>/src/main.html` instead of `<project root>/index.html`, you can access it at `http://localhost:3000/src/main.html`, but not at simply `localhost:3000`.

To serve files from a different path, you'll need to set [`root`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#root) in the config file.  Note that you'll also need to define other paths relative to this new root, like `dist`.  Otherwise, the packaged files will be output to `/src/dist`.

A more complete config file that loads the HTML file from `/src` looks like this:

```js
import path from "node:path";
import process from "node:process";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    open: "main.html",
  },
  root: "src",
  publicDir: "../public",
  build: {
    outDir: "../dist"
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: { "/src": path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src") }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 7):

For anyone trying to serve an `index.html` file that's somewhere deep in your source files, but wants the dev server to actually serve this on `/`, you can do it with a vite plugin like this, in your `vite.config`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    {
      name: "deep-index",
      configureServer(server) {
        server.middlewares.use(
          (req, res, next) => {
            if (req.url === '/') {
              req.url = '/some/path/to/your/index.html';
            }
            next();
          }
        )
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Regarding next, do i need to call it at the end?

Comment: @elpddev good point, I think it should be called indeed. It worked in my case anyway, but I guess it only works when there's no other middleware

Answer (score 7):

### **Use Vite's transformIndexHtml() to swap HTML content**

There may be more efficient ways, but this method may have a place in special use cases.

**TLDR:** *At build-time*, we swap the content of index.html with that of another html file.

For my use-case, a project temporarily needed two variants of static build outputs: 1. a Vue app, 2. a plain JS app. Swapping `index.html` content was the most straightforward way to achieve that with a little less complication.

For this a file transformation occurs (using `fs`), and is fine during the one-time build step of a project. If, in another context, there would be regular file operations (not one-time), performance might be an issue.

[Vite docs: transformIndexHTML()](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#transformindexhtml)

**1. Have multiple html source files**

At least one `index.html` is required; make your own variations of it.

```
index.html
index_type1.html
index_type2.html
whatever.html
etc
```

**2. Make an HTML-replacement plugin in your vite.config**

Here we make a plugin inline directly in the vite config. This will overwrite index.html with whatever source file you choose. It happens before other build steps, and is basically the equivalent of you manually renaming files before running `build`.

**vite.config.js**

```
import fs from 'fs/promises'

export default defineConfig({

    plugins: [
      // ...

      {
        name: 'my-plugin-for-index-html-build-replacement',
        transformIndexHtml: {
          enforce: 'pre', // Tells Vite to run this before other processes
          async transform() {

            // Do some logic; whatever you want
            if (env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE == 'myType2') {

              // Grab new HTML content to place into index.html
              return await fs.readFile('./index_type2.html', 'utf8')
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // ...
    ]

})
```

Answer (score 3):

When developing an app with Vite, `index.html` is the entry point. You can adjust it by setting `build.rollupOptions.input` to `./main.html`.

In [**Library Mode**](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode), the entry point is the one specified by `build.lib.entry` rather than `index.html`. In this case, the `index.html` demo page is only relevant for the dev server, which will automatically transform any files ending in `.html`, so you simply need to open http://localhost:3000/main.html, without adjusting the config. Setting `build.rollupOptions.input` in library mode will override the entry point specified by `build.lib.entry` and bundle the demo page code as part of the library, along with breaking the global UMD export.

Answer (score 0):

It's the server.open property, this is from their site, ChatGPT has failed once again:)

```js
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    open: '/docs/index.html'
  }
})
```

Comment: Not sure how this is an answer. This opens a browser after the server has started. https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options#server-open

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem with Vite and react. Wanted to serve different html files. No problem with the build. Only serve.

The only solution that worked was to add the plugin:

```
export default defineConfig(({command, mode, isSsrBuild, isPreview}) => {
 return {
   plugins: [..., {
        name: 'index-html-build-replacement', 
        apply: 'serve',  
        async transformIndexHtml(html) {
            switch (mode) {
                case  'firstMode':
                    return await fs.readFile('./index-first.html','utf8'); 
                case 'secondMode':
                    return await fs.readFile('./index-second.html','utf8');
            }

            return html;
        }
     }],
     ...
    }
  }
```

You can set the mode via the Vite env configuration.

https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode