# How can I update the generated HTML file name for production?

Tags: vue.js, vite

Is there a way to configure the HTML file name that is produced for a production build in Vite?

I've been playing about with the Rollup options and can see how to change the bundled JS files but not able to affect the produced HTML.

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    assetsDir: '.', // Output assets to the root of the dist directory
    rollupOptions: {
      input: 'src/main.js', // Adjust the entry file path as needed
      output: {
        entryFileNames: 'home.[hash].js', // Adjust the output file name
        chunkFileNames: 'home.[hash].js', // Adjust the chunk file name
        assetFileNames: 'home.[hash].[ext]', // Adjust the asset file name
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: You mean `index.html`? Why would you want a different name?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah id like to configure a name change to this....existing project that im moving

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In vite, is there a way to update the root html name from index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71295772/in-vite-is-there-a-way-to-update-the-root-html-name-from-index-html)

Comment: i actually asked that question :) ... this more the other way around. outputting a file with a different name